# Password protecting a child theme only?

Tags: magento2, parent-child-theme

**Magento 2.4.6**

Is it somehow possible to password protect a child theme only? I am using the porto theme and created a porto_child folder. The porto_child folder is used only by one store and it should only be accessible with a password.

Possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve restricted access through server configuration or custom module development.

Here are two approaches:

****1**. Server Configuration**

For Apache:
Use **.htaccess** and **.htpasswd** files.

Create a **.htpasswd** file outside your public web directory or in a secure location with the usernames and encrypted passwords.

In your Magento root **.htaccess** or preferably, in the configuration specific to your store view (if separated in directories or through virtual hosts), add the following:

**<Directory "/path/to/magento2/root/">**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

****2**. Custom Module Development**

Developing a custom module to prompt for authentication when accessing pages of a specific store view that uses the child theme.

This approach allows for more granular control and integration within Magento but requires development effort.

Implement an observer for the **controller_action_predispatch** event.

In the observer, check if the current store view matches the one you wish to protect.
If it matches, implement your logic to check for authentication (e.g., check if a session variable is set).

If not authenticated, redirect to a custom login page.